# After click submit button

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-2

```
 <%  using (Html.BeginAbsoluteRouteForm("PetDetail", new { controller = "Customers", action = "SavePetSitterRestrictionsAndPermissions", ownerKey = Model.Owner.Key, petKey = Model.Key }))
        { %>

              <button type="submit" class="actionButton default">
                Save</button>

    <% }
 } %>
```

I am having above like code for `submit a form`.I need to `disable a save button` after click the save button.

By using **jquery** how to do that?

I tried something looks like below:

```
var clickedBttn=$('.actionButton.default[type=submit][clicked=true]').val()

if (clickedBttn)
{
//btton disable code here
}
```

But `never fires` above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply register click event for that button:

```
$('.actionButton.default[type=submit]').click(function(){
   $(this).prop("disabled", true);
})
```

Also, I know nothing like [clicked] attribute, so if do not set it somewhere, jquery will find nothing here `$('.actionButton.default[type=submit][clicked=true]')`

Comment: when i registered a "click event" will it fire my normal "form submit" operation ? Which is the order it happens ? Is that click fires after submit or what ?

Comment: Click is fired before actual submit. But I do not think that should be a problem. Actually, you may change it to `$("#PetDetail").submit(function(){$('.actionButton.default[type=submit]').prop("disabled", true);})`

Comment: Could I use above mentioned code with my normal html code which I have mentioned on my question above or should I change my html code also (form post code)? Here "#PetDetail"  is form id ?

Comment: Not clear what code you refer to. #PetDetail is a form ID, that is correct. Both code snippets should work with your HTML (maybe only problem is form ID, not show if PetDetail is correct ID).

Comment: Yes actually I have to set form id (currently it's dynamic).You mentioned my "route name".Any way I will try and get back to you.

Comment: +1 for invaluable information.I have used "submit" method you have mentioned on your comment.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('.actionButton').click(function(){
    $('p').text("Form submiting.....");
    $('input:submit').attr("disabled", true);   
});
```

Comment: `$('input:submit')` - this will disable all submit buttons, not only save  button

Answer (score 0):

Simply obtaining a reference to the text property of the clicked button will not do what you want unfortunately.  Some additional research will help here.  I advise reading up on the click() jQuery method - http://api.jquery.com/click/

```
$('.actionButton.default[type=submit][clicked=true]').click(function() {
    // button disable code here
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
});
```